# Minio C# Continuation Token/Get More than 1000 Items

Tags: c#, .net, minio

I'm using Minio S3 Storage and using C#/.NET to upload and download files from object storage.  I'm running into an issue with retrieving more than 1000 items. Every example that I've read thus far has pointed me to using the 'continuation-token' parameter but I'm not sure how to generate this. The following is code snippet that I've tried thus far and I still can't retrieve more that 1000 items

```
            List<Item> items = new List<Item>();
            try
            {
                var bucketExistsArgs = new BucketExistsArgs().WithBucket(bucketName);
                // List of objects with version IDs.
                // Check whether 'mybucket' exists or not.
                bool found = await client.BucketExistsAsync(bucketExistsArgs, CancellationToken.None);
                if (found)
                {
                    var headers = new Dictionary<string, string>();
                    headers.Add("continuation-token", "1000");
                    // List objects from 'my-bucketname'
                    ListObjectsArgs args = new ListObjectsArgs()
                        .WithBucket(bucketName)
                        //.WithHeaders(headers)
                        .WithPrefix(folderPath);
                    IObservable<Item> observable = client.ListObjectsAsync(args, CancellationToken.None);
                    IDisposable subscription = observable.Subscribe(
                            item => items.Add(item),
                            ex => Console.WriteLine("OnError: {0}", ex.Message),
                            () => Console.WriteLine("OnComplete: {0}"));
                    observable.Wait();
                    
                }
                else
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("mybucket does not exist");
                }
            }
            catch (MinioException e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Error occurred: " + e);
            }

            return items;
```

Comment: [This page](https://docs.min.io/docs/minio-server-limits-per-tenant.html) seems to suggest that this is a hard limit.

Comment: Generally speaking a continuation token is returned as a Header on the response returning the first resources. You then specify that in your next request to get the following items. Could you check if there is anything of the sort in the result object returned by `client.ListObjectsAsync` ?

Comment: So the ListObjectsAsync returns an IObservable<Item> and not  Response object (i.e. GetObjectResponse on the GetObjectAsync method).  All I can do is Wait the observable and get a list of Items (actual bucket objects) returned to me at a limit of 1000;